# Custom JSON Parser for Dates in Typescript in different classes

Tags: java, json, angular, typescript

I have an Angular WebApp who retrives data from a backend Java server via http get.
Example:

```
public getStateForUser(): Observable<UserRegistrationState> {
   return this.http.get<any>(Environment.getServerAddress() + '/' + 
   UserRegistrationStateService.SERVICE_URL + '/getStateForUser', {
      params: {
        sessionIdentityStr: this.authGuard.getSession().sessionIdentityStr
      }
   });
}

export class UserRegistrationState {
  registerDate: Date;
  emailVerified: boolean;
  unlocked: boolean;
}
```

This works fine for all fields. Except the Dates. **The Dates are not parsed correctly, so I want to add a custom parser where I can tell him how he gets the date value from the json date string.**

Of course now I can add a custom Parser for the whole `UserRegistrationState` class, but I have Dates on multiple classes and I do not want to create a Parser for every class, because the other properties(except the Dates) are parsed fine.

So my question: Is there a way to add a custom parser for all Date fields?

P.S. This is an example JSON date string, automatically parsed from a Java `LocalDateTime`:

```
"registerDate":{"dayOfMonth":17,"dayOfWeek":"WEDNESDAY","dayOfYear":290,"month":"OCTOBER","monthValue":10,"year":2018,"hour":21,"minute":21,"nano":370000000,"second":16,"chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"}}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to format and send the date as a string of milliseconds since epoch and use a date pipe to get the format you need?

Comment: Tell the author of that Java backend server to learn about the ISO 8601 standard. These standard text formats are supported by default in the *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 1):

This unfriendly date format is probably caused by backend. I never had any problems with dates from any API in Angular.

You can create getters/setters to encapsulate custom parsing logic for some field in your class.

In my opinion would be better to fix backend side and move from classes to interfaces in Angular side. Interfaces are better for plain DTO models in TypeScript.